# Past-participles Grammar in use

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, past-participles, participles

Can I say so? Is it right in terms of grammar?

> it was wrong to meet him without **having had talked** before

I know for sure that it's correct to say:

> without having talked

but I mean exactly the past perfect time

Comment: *Having talked* is the correct participial past perfect. *Having had talked* is not a permissible construction--the perfect auxiliary *HAVE* can only appear once.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to say *having talked* but not *having had talked*. The verb constructions / participles don't fit together. After *having had* you would need a noun for the sentence to be correct.

Example:

- it was wrong to meet him without having had a discussion before

Answer (score 0):

"Having talked" is correct.  "Having had talked" is never correct.

Just to add to the existing answer: you suggested that "having had talked" might be appropriate because you're referring to "past perfect time".  So you might be thinking of "having talked" as a use of the present perfect.  This would be wrong.

"Having talked" is perfect, but it's not present perfect.  Participles such as "having" are non-finite and have no tense.  So there is no past equivalent of "having talked" because "having talked" isn't a present tense form (or any tense at all) in the first place.